# Spearman - pairwise correlation

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame who looks like this (the real ones has 7000+ rows and 17 columns):

```
     V1    V2   V3    V4
1    93    98   79    170
2    17    17   22    85
3    1    57    137   320
4    9    1     0     440
5    NA    NA   NA    22
```

I would like to do pairwise spearman correlations for each column, and extract the correlation coefficient estimates for each pairwise comparison.

I tried the rcor function but the output is just NA:

```
rcor.test(data.matrix(data), method = "spearman")

      V1        V2        V3      V4
V1    ******    NA        NA      NA
V2    <0.001    *****     NA      NA
V3    <0.001    <0.001    *****   NA
V3    <0.001    <0.001    <0.001  *****
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I tried to use the data frame as a matrix but no luck

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the classes of your data, e.i. `sapply(data, class)` gives you? With your example `rcor.test(data, method = "spearman")` works just fine. Though the upper triangle supposed to be `NA` and the lower triangle could be valid if you had very low correlation. Either way, if you have `factor` classes there, `data.matrix` will convert them incorrectly

Comment: The classes are all numeric

Comment: If I use a simple cor.test for two columns it works fine

Comment: the rcor test with the data frame does not work either

Comment: It works fine with the data set you provided. You should also probably mention the packages you are using.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I just said it may be useful to add this to the question itself. Either way, I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and `use="pairwise.complete.obs"` solved it